# Find Item Of Structure in List (Of Structure)

Tags: vb.net, list

I have a struct:

```
Private Structure udtT9Map
    Dim KeyboardKey As String
    Dim MobileButton As Integer
End Structure
```

They are stored in

```
Private _List As List(Of udtT9Map)
```

I would like to know if there is a really fast way to locate an item in the List by just giving a certain KeyboardKey.

Since e. g. "KeyboardKey" could theoretically occur multiple times, I guess MS did not include such a function because multiple items from the list would be returned.

Am I wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: 'Really Fast' can mean two things: Fast and simple to code and understand, or fast execution. Guffa's answer provides fast execution *for large lists* at the expense of complication. Simply using the `List<T>.Find` method, as suggested by MarcinJuraszek would be much simpler and likely almost as fast for small `n` and/or a low number of repeat lookups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list doesn't have any means of quickly finding items. Locating the items in the list would be an O(n) operation, i.e. you need to loop through the entire list and compare the value from each structure. For fast lookup you would rather use a dictionary of lists:

```
Private _Dict as Dictionary(Of String, List(Of udtT9Map))
```

By storing all structures with the same `KeyboardKey` value in a list in the dictionary using the `KeyboardKey` value as key, you can get all the structures with that value very fast. Reading from a dictionary is close to an O(1) operation.

To get the list you use:

```
Dim result as List(Of udtT9Map) = _Dict(key)
```

If your `KeyboardKey` values are known to be unique in your collection, then you don't need a dictionary of lists, you can use a dictionary of the structure:

```
Private _Dict as Dictionary(Of String, udtT9Map)
```

To get the item you use:

```
Dim result as udtT9Map = _Dict(key)
```

Comment: Could you please add "            Dim nItem As udtT9Map = _Dict.Item(sChar)
" to find the required item? It think this would make your post complete. Thank you!

Comment: Or even better:                Dim nItem As udtT9Map = Nothing
            Dim bFound As Boolean = _Dict.TryGetValue(sChar, nItem)           This one can easily be caught.    Sorry, stackoverflow does not really like formatting code.

Answer (score 1):

There is couple possible ways of doing that:

1. Create a lookup dictionary to get *O(1)* lookup:

   ```
   Dim _dict = _List.GroupBy(Function(x) x.KeyboardKey)
                    .ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(x) x.ToList())
   ```
2. Sort your list and use `BinarySearch` to get *O(log n)* search complexity. You'd have to either declare your own `Comparer(Of T)` to search by a property value, or write your own `BinarySearchBy` methods.
3. Use standard `Find` method to get *O(n)* complexity. It will return the first element matching given condition.

Comment: "Find" is not a method of Dictionary.

Comment: Find is a method on `List<T>`.